# Possible HttpClient deadlock

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0

I have a decorator class that adds the ability to rate limit http requests for hitting an API:

```
public class RateLimitedHttpClient : IHttpClient
{
    public RateLimitedHttpClient(System.Net.Http.HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
        _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    }
    public async Task<string> ReadAsync(string url)
    {
        if (!_sw.IsRunning)
            _sw.Start();

        await Delay();

        using var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    private async Task Delay()
    {
        var totalElapsed = GetTimeElapsedSinceLastRequest();

        while (totalElapsed < MinTimeBetweenRequests)
        {
            await Task.Delay(MinTimeBetweenRequests - totalElapsed);
            totalElapsed = GetTimeElapsedSinceLastRequest();
        };

        _timeElapsedOfLastHttpRequest = (int)_sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    private int GetTimeElapsedSinceLastRequest()
    {
        return (int)_sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds - _timeElapsedOfLastHttpRequest;
    }

    private readonly System.Net.Http.HttpClient _client;
    private readonly Stopwatch _sw = new Stopwatch();
    private int _timeElapsedOfLastHttpRequest;
    private const int MinTimeBetweenRequests = 100;
}
```

However, I'm noticing that at the line indicated below I get a message in the debugger that says that `the next statement will execute when the current thread returns`.

```
var epsDataPoints = await _downloader.GetEPSData(cik);

foreach (var eps in epsDataPoints)
{
     // getting VS2019 debugger message here!
     // assuming that the line above is deadlocking....
     Console.WriteLine($"{cik} :: {eps.DateInterval} :: {eps.EPS}");
}
```

When I open up the Task Manager, the network bandwidth goes to 0 and everything stops with the application other than it sitting at the `Console.WriteLine` above.

The EPSDownloader class that uses the IHttpClient is below:

```
public class EPSDownloader
{
    public EPSDownloader(IHttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<EPSDataPoint>> GetEPSData(int cik)
    {
        var epsDataPoints = new Dictionary<LocalDate, EPSDataPoint>();
        var reportLinks = await GetReportLinks(cik);

        foreach (var reportLink in reportLinks)
        {
            var xbrlLink = await GetXBRLLink(reportLink);
            var epsData = await GetEPSData(xbrlLink);

            foreach (var eps in epsData)
            {
                if (!epsDataPoints.ContainsKey(eps.DateInterval.End))
                    epsDataPoints.Add(eps.DateInterval.End, eps);
            }
        }

        var list = epsDataPoints.OrderBy(d => d.Key).Select(e => e.Value).ToList();

        return list;
    }

    private async Task<IList<string>> GetReportLinks(int cik)
    {
        // move this url elsewhere
        var url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=" + cik +
                  "&type=10&dateb=&owner=include&count=100";

        var srBody = await _client.ReadAsync(url); // consider moving this to srPage
        var srPage = new SearchResultsPage(srBody);

        return srPage.GetAllReportLinks();
    }

    private async Task<string> GetXBRLLink(string link)
    {
        var url = SEC_HOSTNAME + link;

        var fdBody = await _client.ReadAsync(url);
        var fdPage = new FilingDetailsPage(fdBody);

        return fdPage.GetInstanceDocumentLink();
    }

    private async Task<IList<EPSDataPoint>> GetEPSData(string xbrlLink)
    {
        var xbrlBody = await _client.ReadAsync(SEC_HOSTNAME + xbrlLink);
        var xbrlDoc = new XBRLDocument(xbrlBody);

        return xbrlDoc.GetAllQuarterlyEPSData();
    }

    private readonly IHttpClient _client;
    private const string SEC_HOSTNAME = "https://www.sec.gov";
}
```

It seems to be that there is an issue with HttpClient, but I don't know why. No exceptions are being thrown, but I do occasionally see that threads have exited with code 0.

Update: I actually restarted my computer while the application was running and it began running fine again for about 20 minutes before the Task Manager showed 0 for the network speed and the application just sat there.

Comment: Class you have shown is not represented in the place you are calling it, meaning, we don't know how you are calling the class. Is this async all the way up the call stack?

Comment: @TheGeneral fixed! Added the additionally calling methods.

Comment: I see a lot of unprotected private variables; I suspect it may have something to do with that. If you reduce the code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you'll probably find it fairly quickly.